# Searching in descriptions of available R packages

Tags: r

I was searching for "DDE" phrase in list of all available packages, but found nothing, because output of `available.packages()` doesn't contain packages descriptions.
The package I was searching for is `tcltk2` which [description](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tcltk2/index.html) is :

*"A series of additional Tcl commands and Tk widgets with style and various functions (under Windows: **DDE** exchange, access to the registry and icon manipulation) to supplement the tcltk package"*

and on the [web page with all CRAN hosted packages](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/available_packages_by_name.html) we have only very short one :

*"Tcl/Tk Additions"*

so simple `CTRL+F` doesn't find it there. How to search packages with "DDE" in its description (eition after  **Sean Hughes** comment):
1. Is it online resource for that ?
2. Is there programmatic solution (based on R and without connecting to online search engines) ?

Comment: Google `"DDE" site:cran.r-project.org/web/packages/`

Comment: note that the solutions below *do* connect to online search engines.

Comment: Just a sidenote, if you need a package to use dde from R, I have developed  a package that provides a faster connection than tcltk2, https://bitbucket.org/juancentro/rdde

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This R command:

```
RSiteSearch("DDE")
```

brings up a reference to tcltk2 in your browser in the 10 hit

[image]

and these R commands:

```
library(sos)
???DDE
```

bring up a reference to tcltk2 on the 30th and 31st hits:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I find the `sos`-package very useful. Thank you, Spencer Graves.

All of these searches were "sensitive" (but there were quite a few where DDE meant "delay differential equations") , so only the last one was "specific";

```
install.packages("sos")
library(sos)

> findFn("DDE")
found 75 matches;  retrieving 4 pages
2 3 4 
Downloaded 35 links in 9 packages.
> findFn("Dynamic Data Exchange")
found 69 matches;  retrieving 4 pages
2 3 4 
Downloaded 25 links in 16 packages.
> findFn("Dynamic Data Exchange DDE")
found 4 matches;  retrieving 1 page

Downloaded 2 links in 1 packages.
```

They each popup a page in my browser:

[image]